# Raspbian can't print() utf-8 multibyte characters?

Tags: python, python-3.x, utf-8, raspbian

**Important:** This happens only if you are runing python3 on the console of the raspberry pi ( no ssh ), using Raspbian

**So here is the code that causes trouble:**

```
string = "silence on joue ! €"
byte_string = string.encode( 'ascii', 'ignore' )
print ( byte_string )
print ( string )
```

**Console output**

```
b'silence on joue ! €'
UnicodeEncodeError 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\u20ac' in position 18 ordinal not in range(128)
```

So it would seem that print() does an implicit call to encode but that any errors throws an exception.

This code runs fine on windows. Not cool.

Right now my solution is to do a call to encode( 'ascii', 'ignore' ) before each print. But that sucks because I have the b'' that is suddenly printed along with the string. Also extra code.

Any ideas? is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your console configuration is telling Python that it is configured to handle only ASCII.

You'll need to adjust that configuration; Python looks at the `LC_CTYPE` environment variable, which is a subset of the `LC_ALL` variable which in turn is derived from `LANG`. You can see your configuration by running:

```
locale
```

in the terminal. You can run:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

to reconfigure what locales are available, or set a `LANG` environment variable in your `profile` file. Also see the [Debian Locale wiki page](https://wiki.debian.org/Locale), especially the *Standard* section, on what this means. For the console, I'd use the `${LANG:=<locale>.<encoding>}; export LANG` approach as that'll set a sensible default for the console but allows for a SSH connection to specify a different locale.

You can try out individual settings first, by using:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF8 python
```

for example; this picks the US english locale with UTF-8 encoding.

If you *have* to encode to ASCII, you can always *decode* again to produce a ASCII-save Unicode string object:

```
print(string.encode('ascii', 'replace').decode('ascii'))
```

but that's not an approach I'd use.

Comment: Thanks for this solid answer!

Ok so I tried a few things

First I tried :

sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales

It asks me locales to be generated:

[ ] All locales

[ ] aa_DJ ISO-8859-1

[ ] aa_DJ.UTF-8 UTF-8
[ ] aa_ER UTF-8
[ ] aa_ER@saaho UTF-8
I tried both aa_DJ.UTF-8 UTF-8 and aa_ER UTF-8 and rebooted, to no avail.
 
Then I tried to add
: ${LANG:=en_GB.UTF-8}; export LANG
To /etc/profile and rebooted to no avail

Also the command locale shows
LANGUAGE=*nothing*

Comment: @OeilDeLance: the `${LANG:=de_DE.iso88591}` syntax sets the environment variable *if not already set*. That's great for the console configuration, as it won't interfere with a SSH connection setting. But take into account that IS88591 doesn't cover all of Unicode, you'd be better off with UTF-8.

Comment: @OeilDeLance: did you set that entry in your `/etc/profile`? And what does the `locale` command show?

Comment: @OeilDeLance: presumably using `LANG=en_GB.UTF-8 python` in the console makes things work for just that invocation of Python? Because the console itself has to be correctly configured to handle UTF-8 being written to it by Python.

Comment: @OeilDeLance: I see that the Raspberry PI Stack Exchange also has [some information about this](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/1132/which-locale-should-i-select-during-the-raspbian-setup).

Comment: Okay so thanks to that link I was able to actually change the local to en_US.UTF-8. The 'locale' command shows "LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=" I wonder why LANGUAGE is null

Comment: @OeilDeLance: you don't have to worry about `LANGUAGE` there; it is the `LANG` variable that counts here and informs the other values. You can set any of the others explicitly to override.

Comment: Okay I finally have some interesting results: I am executing by program this way: "sudo LANG=en_US.UTF-8 python3 myProgram.py" and the string finally prints! But the € is printed a an invalid character ( a square ). Wht can I do to avoid aving to add LANG=en_US.UTF-8 to the python session?

Comment: @OeilDeLance: it means your console itself doesn't handle the UTF-8 bytes; I'm not 100% sure how that configuration is handled. First of all, you do have the UTF-8 locale generated? Does `locale -a` list UTF-8 locales? It may be that the console cannot handle Unicode at all, the [rather long in the tooth Unicode HOWTO](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Unicode-HOWTO-2.html#ss2.1) suggests Unicode on the console is limited, but the [Linux from Scratch info is more hopeful](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/6.3/chapter07/console.html)

Comment: @OeilDeLance: further research: Debian (Raspbian) uses the `console-tools` package to handle console fonts and configuration. And I see there's a [console-setup](https://packages.debian.org/sid/console-setup) package that looks applicable.

Comment: local -a shows: "
C
C.UTF-8
en_GB.utf8
en_US.utf8
POSIX
" But I guess that is fine I mean even if it doesn't support unicode character I don't mind so much. What I care about is avoiding using "LANG=en_US.UTF-8" when calling the program it makes the command line way too long